# Ubuntu (budgie) 21.10 random freeze

Tags: kernel, graphics, intel-graphics, freeze, 21.10

```
 Ubuntu (**Budgie**) 21.10 freezes at a random time.
 PC info:
 Host: 81TD Lenovo Yoga C740-15IML
 Kernel: 5.13.0-20-generic 
 CPU: Intel i7-10510U
 GPU: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics]
 (Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)



 free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       2,7Gi       4,8Gi       631Mi       7,8Gi        11Gi
Swap:          979Mi       2,0Mi       977Mi
```

As far as my knowledge goes, Intel GPU drivers are updated VIA kernel releases and so.
I was googling around for similar errors, which occur to people using dual GPU or just Intel GPU. And so far, the best solution is to downgrade to the kernel version that was released on Ubuntu 20.01 ( not sure what version it was ). But, so far, I didn't try that.

I'm thinking of upgrading kernel 5.14.xx. ( using ukuu app ) If so, what version is stable?

Or do I downgrade to some kernel version? And again, what is one to go so?

At first, I thought my GPU would be a happy place and needed to replace MBO.
PIC of freeze: https://ibb.co/ZVybnt6
When it freeze, the only thing that helps is force power-off.
I'm not good at log files, so not sure how to provide them. ( if they get recorded at all )

This issue was reported as a kernel bug and so far was not fixed.
If any have some words of wisdom, please share it or how to deal with it...

```
❯ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition   1003516 0   -2
❯ grep -i swap /etc/fstab~
grep: /etc/fstab~: No such file or directory
❯ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu--budgie-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
❯ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-2                               partition   1003516 0   -2
❯ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu--budgie-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
❯ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
BNCN43WW
```

Comment: When I first looked at your question, I thought swap problem, with only 1G swap, but then I looked at your screenshot. That's not a swap problem. The Intel video uses shared memory. So, first things first. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema
Will try that.
Is there any other opinion on possible problems ? Increase swap size ?
Note. I'm using ubuntu LUKS encryption for SSD. Is there any possible issue that I might run to it ?

Comment: We'll discuss the possible swap problem after you run memtest.

Comment: @heynnema All PASS ok: https://ibb.co/4d3H8FW
Also got some read: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/08/linux-kernel-5-14-new-features for kernel 5.14. So far I didn't try it

Comment: Edit your question and show me `swapon -s` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Show me the output of `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`.

Comment: @heynnema
```❯ swapon -s
Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/dev/dm-2 ```


```❯ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu--budgie-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0```

```❯ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
BNCN43WW```

Before i run followed the answer to edit swap. In GPARTED/Disk I find that swap location says is: /dev/vgubuntu-budgie/swap_1

Comment: Yes, that swap partition complicates things a bit. Normally I'd create a /swapfile and delete the swap partition. Or just enlarge the current swap partition, but that's a bit more complicated (unless you have enough experience to do this). I'll modify my answer in such a way that you can try two swaps, and you'll still be able to go back if it proves not to help.

Comment: Your BIOS is current.

Comment: I modified my answer. You'll end up with two swap areas... /swapfile and /dev/dm-2. If it doesn't fix the problem, we can still easily go back to the prior setup. Report back.

Answer (score 0):

As promised, here's the info about adding a 4G /swapfile to your system.

It's a bit more complicated as you already have a LVM swap partition, but this will create an additional /swapfile, and will allow you to go back to the prior setup if this doesn't help with the problem.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Leave this line alone...

```
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu--budgie-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Add this additional /swapfile line to the bottom of /etc/fstab... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

`swapon -a` # start all swap locations

`swapon -s` # confirm two swap locations, /swapfile and /dev/dm-2

`reboot` # reboot and verify operation

Comment: all pass without any errors.

Comment: @dMatija What does `free -h` and `swapon -s` show now?

Comment: free -h
```total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       2,5Gi        10Gi       533Mi       2,8Gi        12Gi
Swap:          5,0Gi          0B       5,0Gi'''


Filename    Type  Size Used Priority
/swapfile                               file     4194300 0 -2
/dev/dm-2                               partition 1003516 0 -3```

Comment: Sry for extra edit.
will leave it for a while to check it will all be ok.

Comment: I didn't help. So far from extra swap happened 2x time.
I thought to upgrade the 5.14 kernel or downgrading to kernel version for 20.01

Comment: I try to install 5.14.14 and I was left with freeze-in when choosing a new kernel to load.

Comment: @dMatija Choosing the 5.14 kernel at GRUB time, or some other time?

Comment: @dMatija Show me `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: ```vm.swappiness = 60```
Yes, when I got promoted advance options I get 5.14.14, and it freezes.

Comment: On my 2nd laptop, I put swappiness to 20. Since this is a fresh install I can play with things around. I was thinking to turn off swap memory. 
Not sure will any of that help =/

Comment: Go to BIOS, review your settings, and select "Reset to default" or "Reset to factory", then retest. On the 2nd laptop, vm.swappiness=20 may not be optimal... show me `free -h`.

Comment: ```❯ free -h
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi       1,9Gi        11Gi       293Mi       1,8Gi        12Gi
Swap:          5,0Gi          0B       5,0Gi```
I try before to reset do default. no help. i tryed one more time now.

Comment: @dMatija I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: The only thing i notice after we added extra swap is that there is no visual freeze. Just freeze.
Ill try to reinstall without swap or turn it off. Or might try without LUSK encryption. 
no idea rly =/

Comment: @dMatija Every machine needs some swap. Too small and it may freeze. Keep me posted if you get it fixed.

Comment: Will try to downgrade to kernel 5.8 and 5.4 and will check if any changes.
There is few links I check with same issue that was resolved with downgrading.
Will keep it posted

Comment: @dMatija Status please...

Comment: ATM im not home and using that laptop. Will post some info in Monday or soon as I get home...

Comment: Nothing changes. Laptop with Kali/Ubuntu ( dual boot. No LUSK encryption ), and things are the same after some minor dist-upgrade.For kali, I got a 1x random freeze in time around 4-5 hours of idle. For ubuntu is far way worse. Bad is when I got 4-5 freeze in an hour of middle working. At best, I got 4-5 in 3-4 hours.
 
For laptops with Nvidia, all work without any issue at all. That laptop, I can switch to intel chip, and things happen like on the first laptop. I try some things to change things and stuff, not sure anymore what. ATM, I'm exhausted. Lack of idea at all and will

Comment: @dMatija What kernel versions do you have in /boot? Which one are you running? `uname -r`

Comment: 5.13.0-21-generic - is ubuntu
5,14,0-kali2-amd64 - is kali
For the last 10ish days, I'm a bit busy with work. So I didn't have lots of time to test for some things. I just holding to kernel bug for sure as the main problem.

Comment: To say that nothing changed. I tried some extra stuff that I found online, and as for the most people, it didn't work for me also. So far, I know it is a bug due to some null pointer or something that makes an issue when the laptop needs to start fan to cool CPU/GPU in inlet chip and bugs out. I'm slightly disappointed in the development of this issue just there are lots of people with this issue.