# Errors installing mainline kernel 5.16 on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04

Tags: kernel, intel

I am using Ubuntu Budgie 20.04.3. I currently have the default kernel 5.11.  I am trying to install a mainline kernel version 5.16.

The laptop is a Lenovo Yoga C-740 with an Intel i7-10510U CPU with integrated Intel CometLake-U GT2 graphics.

I tried to use the Ubuntu Mainline installer and after trying to install I got this error:

[image]

When I try to download manually from the browser, I get this:

```
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.16.0-051600.
(Reading database ... 337279 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.16.0-051600_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.16.0-051600 (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic_5.16.0-051600.202201092355_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
Setting up linux-headers-5.16.0-051600 (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic:
 linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.34); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.31-0ubuntu9.2.
 linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic depends on libssl3 (>= 3.0.0~~alpha1); however:
  Package libssl3 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
I: /boot/vmlinuz.old is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.11.0-44-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img.old is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.11.0-44-generic
I: /boot/vmlinuz is now a symlink to vmlinuz-5.16.0-051600-generic
I: /boot/initrd.img is now a symlink to initrd.img-5.16.0-051600-generic
Setting up linux-modules-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-unsigned-5.16.0-051600-generic (5.16.0-051600.202201092355) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0-051600-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/glk_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/cml_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/icl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/ehl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/dg1_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_guc_62.0.0.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_huc_7.9.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/adlp_guc_62.0.3.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/tgl_dmc_ver2_12.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/rkl_dmc_ver2_03.bin for module i915
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/dm-2
I: (/dev/mapper/vgubuntu--budgie-swap_1)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.16.0-051600-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.16.0-051600-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-43-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-headers-5.16.0-051600-generic
```

On the website, there are two versions: generic and low-latency.

I downloaded the generic one.

Since I don't understand much about the technical side of the kernel, are there any words of wisdom to help solve this?

Comment: Why do you want/need the mainline kernel?  Mainline builds are for testing only. Bugs are expected. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds

Comment: @Nmath I have an intel GPU that has a bug in the current kernel.
The bug is reported just is not solved so far.
And i wish to try installing a new one in hope that will be solved in this version.
So far via mainline software, I was able to install any other kernel. just this one i got these errors

Comment: @Nmath GPU. not CPU.
Is well known bug that was discussed on this link
https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels

and here
https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=270704
As far i get it is due to null pointer on kernel that have some things with fan/cooling

Comment: @Nmath
I had one topic with this issue i talk
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371569/ubuntu-budgie-21-10-random-freeze/1371718?noredirect=1#comment2367952_1371718

Comment: Try not using mainline but downloading the files directly and dpkg -i them.  Try the instructions here: https://nextgentips.com/2021/12/14/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-5-16-release/